# Completely left align text in table

Tags: tables, alignment

I am using tabular and trying to left align text in cells completely to the border of the table.
Which parameters do I have to use to delete these white space?

[image]
Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage{longtable}  
\usepackage{multirow,makecell,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
   \begin{tabular}{|L{12cm}C{4cm}}
       \textbf{Home address}:  &    \\
       \textbf{Personal E-mail}: &  \\
       \textbf{Mobile phone}:  &    \\
       \textbf{Skype}:  &   \\
       \textbf{Citizenship}:  & \\
   \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a MWE (start with \documentclass and ending with \end{document} of how you already obtained the above image / document.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{|@{}l ...}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the alignment operator: `@{<LaTeXCode>}`. You can replace `<LaTeXCode>` with any latex code that should be used to separate the column. There is a default setting that is set to some width, but I can't seem to figure it out. Anyways, here is a modified version of your code that removes the space.

That is: I put in, before the first `l`, an empty specifier: `@{}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{tabular}{|@{}ll}
        \textbf{Home address}:    & Home address    \\
        \textbf{Personal E-mail}: & Personal E-mail \\
        \textbf{Mobile phone}:    & Mobile phone    \\
        \textbf{Skype}:           & Skype           \\
        \textbf{Citizenship}:     & Citizenship     \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You can experiment with this: try inserting e.g. `@{=}` between some of the letters, or `@{\hskip 4em}`.

Note that I don't know how you defined your `L` and `C`, so I just replaced them with `ll` (both left adjusted). I also removed the width specification in your alignment parameters. Also, I removed the unused packages.